# WPF: Querying user with Modal Dialog box / InputDialog

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, textinput

In a WPF application I have to get one line of info from user and I wan't to use a Modal Dialog. However there seems to be no preset dialog for this. What's a simple and easy way to do this. I find it somwhat complicated trying to find this out with the many versions of Dialogs and such.

Already I have had to use OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog. What is the different between version of these like Microsoft.Win32 and System.Windows.Form ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do to show a modal dialog in WPF. Just add a `Window` to your project (let's say the class name is `MyDialog`), and then do:

```
var dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

[`Window.ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) takes care of showing the window in a modal manner.

**Example:**

```
public class MyDialog : Window {
    public MyDialog() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DialogResult = null;
    }

    public string SomeData { get; set; } // bind this to a control in XAML
    public int SomeOtherData { get; set; } // same for this

    // Attach this to the click event of your "OK" button
    private void OnOKButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }

    // Attach this to the click event of your "Cancel" button
    private void OnCancelButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        this.DialogResult = false;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

In your code somewhere:

```
var dialog = new MyDialog();
// If MyDialog has properties that affect its behavior, set them here
var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

if (result == false) {
    // cancelled
}
else if (result == true) {
    // do something with dialog.SomeData here
}
```

Comment: All good and well but how do you define a inputDialog, what do you inherit from and such?

Comment: @Ingo: you inherit from `Window`. There's nothing special about it.

Comment: I see. Any tutorial you can point me towards as how to return the Bool in the ShowDialog method, and how to access the input and such?

Comment: @Ingo: added an example, hope it helps.

Comment: It's so obvious now that I see it. I never used the WPF Window class before so I wasn't sure what you were talking about initially.